# Get height between TextField and Keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a ViewController that contains a form, and i would like to get the height (distance) between the TextField's bottom Y position and the Keyboard's top Y position.
I made an illustration of what i mean:
[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpzpI.png)
The code i tried but didn't worked:

```
let textFieldBottomY = myTextField.frame.origin.y + myTextField.frame.size.height
let keyboardTopY = self.view.frame.height - keyboardHeight

distanceHeight = keyboardTopY - textFieldBottomY
```

The above function gets called from `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)`
and `keyboardHeight` is from this function:

```
if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardSize = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
}
```

The thing i'm trying to achieve is to draw a `UIView` between the `TextField` and the `Keyboard` The value of `distanceHeight` that i get is incorrect and the height exceeds the keyboard.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: In my experience UIKeyboardWillShow often gets posted twice with different sizes. I believe the second time is after it adds the auto-suggestion bar. Is there any chance your distanceHeight calculation happens the first time and not the second time?

Comment: Use `UIKeyboardDidShow` instead of `UIKeyboardWillShow`.

Comment: show us the code where you are trying to draw a `UIView` between the `TextField` and the `Keyboard`.

Comment: 1. The `UIKeyboardWillShow` is called only once for me.
2. Changed to `UIKeyboardDidShow` but still doesn't work.
3. This is the code i use after i'm getting `distanceHeight`:
`myContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: myTextField
.frame.origin.x, y: myTextField
.frame.origin.y + myTextField
.frame.size.height, width: myTextField
.frame.size.width, height: distanceHeight
))`

Comment: It looks like your code assumes the `superview` of `myTextField` extends to the bottom of the screen. Are there any cases where it doesn't? For example on iPhone X does it extend to the bottom of the screen or is it pinned to the safe area bottom? You might try "Debug View Hierarchy" just to visually inspect that the superview extends to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `keyboardHeight` = 0
if `keyboardWillShow`or `KeyboardWillChangeFrame`
    `keyboardHeight` = `keyboardFrameEnd.height`
else if `keyboardWillHide`
 
    `keyboardHeight` = 0

rest of the code is working fine
**Assuming your textField is a subview of self.view**

```
let textFieldBottomY = tfAny.frame.origin.y + tfAny.frame.size.height
let keyboardTopY = self.view.frame.height - keyboardHeight    
let distanceHeight = abs(keyboardTopY - textFieldBottomY)
```

**else if inside scrollView**

```
let textFieldBottomPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: tfAny.frame.origin.y + tfAny.frame.height)
let textFieldBottomY = scrollView.convert(textFieldBottomPoint, to: view).y
let keyboardTopY = self.view.frame.height - keyboardHeight
let distanceHeight = abs(keyboardTopY - textFieldBottomY)
```

Comment: Thanks man!
I guess the issue was that my entire view was inside a scrollview, so now everything is working!